# How to implement the Progress dialog for this code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, progressdialog

I my application i am going to implement the Progress dialog till its getting loading. . . 
The code is like:

```
copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard("Alone.mp4");
intent = new Intent(this,VideoPlayerController.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

So how to implement it ??
Thanks.

Code for the function is:

```
public void copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard(String fileFromAssets){
    AssetManager is = this.getAssets();
    InputStream fis;
    try {

        fis = is.open(fileFromAssets);
        FileOutputStream fos;

        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileFromAssets));
        byte[] b = new byte[8];
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
            fos.write(b, 0, i);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should show the code that you are trying to copy file from assets to sdcard.

Comment: @Lalit: Yes You are right. But i want to put the Progress dialog for this code only so... ?

Comment: Clarify your question. give more explanation.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer have you got the solution? If not them check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this,

Create an `ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();` and add all the files that you can to copy to SDCard like the below.

```
        files.add("test.png");
        files.add("icon.png");
        new myAsyncTask().execute(files);
```

Then you can just use this ArrayList object to pass to AsynTask and get it done.

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, Void>
    {
        ArrayList<String> files;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mainact.this, "Loading...", "");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {

            files = params[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
                copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard(files.get(i));   
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes Lalit its works as i want. You budy is great. I always accept answer from you and it always works fine. Thanks a Lot. Keep Going and Keep Helping.

Comment: Welcome, I am trying my best to deal if possible.

Comment: Will you help me for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209867/how-to-implement-the-imageadapter-for-this-listview-code

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new progressTask().execute("");
     }

     public void copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard(String fileFromAssets){
         AssetManager is = this.getAssets();
         InputStream fis;
         try {
            fis = is.open(fileFromAssets);
            FileOutputStream fos;

            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileFromAssets));
            byte[] b = new byte[8];
            int i;
            while ((i = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
                fos.write(b, 0, i);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private class progressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
       ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

       @Override  
       protected void onPreExecute() {  
           pd.show();
       } 

       protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
            copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard("Alone.mp4");
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
       }

   }

}
```

I have made a arrangement of your all tasks together. Try it. Hope it will help you out.

Comment: If this code helped you out, please accept this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to move the copy code to a thread and show the dialog, and after thread ends, remove the dialog launch the new activity.

Something like this :

```
showDialog(10);//10 is the dialog id
new Thread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard("Alone.mp4"); 
      handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
   }
}).start();
```

Make a handler to receive the message:

```
Handler handler=new Handler(){
   void handleMessage(Message msg){
    switch(msg.what){
     case 1:
       removeDialog(10);
       intent = new Intent(this,VideoPlayerController.class);
       startActivity(intent); 
       break;
    }
    };
};
```

Comment: why you have take two different objet of progress dialog ?? removeDialog, and startDialog ???

Comment: showDialog(int id) and remove Dialog(int id) are two methods in an Activity which allow you to access dialog created using the onCreateDialog(int id) method of the Activity class. Alternativley you could hold on to one dialog object that you created, something like: ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(context,"Copying", "Please Wait",true); and remove your dialog using the methods : pd.remove();

Answer (score 1):

try this code for Displaying Progress Dialog Box,

`ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Process ", "please wait....",false,true);

new Thread ( new Runnable()
{
        public void run()
        {
              // Put Intent your code here
        }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to implement Copy operation in background thread(during that you want to display progress bar or dialog) and once copy operation is completed then you want to start another activity, if this is the case then i would suggest you to implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and this is the best practice to implement threading process in Android i think, because we developer don't need to take care about Thread Management if we have implemented this AsyncTask.

For your case:

```
private class myBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
 {
     @Override  
     protected void onPreExecute() 
     {  
        // Show Progress bar or dialog
     } 

     protected Long doInBackground(Void... void) {
         // write your Copy from Assets to SDcard code here
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) 
     {
        if(dialog.isShowing())    // if progress dialog is showing
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        // And now Write Start Activity code here
     }
 }
```

### Update:

FYI, just a quick update AsyncTask is known as [**`Painless Threading in Android`**](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html), go through this article and i am sure you will sure come to know about the importance of this concept as compared to general threading implementation.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the Lovely reply. I am going to copy two files from assets to the SDCard. but i want to do it at onCreate Activity. So How to use this AsyncTash ??

Comment: @iDroidExplorer, `new TaskName().execute()` pass on parameters to the constructor or the execute method.

Comment: you can pass any parameters like a single value or array or arraylist inside the execute method, and the same you need to define the Argument type inside the doInBackground() method.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer write the new `myBackgroundTask().execute()` inside the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I have Write this code but it gives me error o NUllPointer Exception.

Comment: why null exception? its better i would suggest you to create a different question with AsyncTask implementation with the code and exception.